# Invoke proxy service from WSO2 ESB to BPEL Workflow process

Tags: soap, bpel, wso2-business-process, wso2-esb

How to invoke Soap proxy service from WSO2 ESB to BPEL workflow process. Any help can be really appreciated.

Comment: See this [link](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2011/01/wso2-esb-by-example-service-chaining/)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps below.

1. Deploy a BPEL process on WSO2 BPS Server. (Login to the BPS Management Console and go to Processes -> Add then select the BPEL Archive(zip) file and upload it. If your BPEL process has external web service invocations, you can be hosted those web services WSO2 App Server or axis2Server)
2. Create a proxy service with payload factory mediator as below. Here payload factory mediaor is used to transform the payload of incoming request to the appropriate format that allow by the request for the BPEL process invocation.

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="bpel_factory"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <p:MultiOperatorServiceRequest xmlns:p="http://wso2.org/bps/operator"><!--Exactly 1 occurrence--><x xmlns="http://wso2.org/bps/operator">$1</x>
                  <!--Exactly 1 occurrence--><y xmlns="http://wso2.org/bps/operator">$2</y>
               </p:MultiOperatorServiceRequest>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg xmlns:m="http://wso2.org/bps/operator"
                    evaluator="xml"
                    expression="//m:MultiOperatorServiceRequest/x"/>
               <arg xmlns:m="http://wso2.org/bps/operator"
                    evaluator="xml"
                    expression="//m:MultiOperatorServiceRequest/y"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://10.100.7.75:9763/services/MultiOperatorService.MultiOperatorServicehttpMultiOperatorServiceBindingEndpoint/"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <respond/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

3. Next you can send a POST request with the payload to the proxy service through POSTMAN and test it.

For more information see http://wokis.blogspot.com/2016/05/invoke-bpel-workflow-from-wso2-esb.html